# Backing up iPhone

Tags: iphone, backup

I haven't been able to back up my iPhone due to connection issues. I have a new phone which I have been using. If I back up the old phone and then restore to the new phone will the new data on the new phone be lost?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, restoring a backup onto an iPhone replaces all its content.